# Some devices that doesn't support app in play store

Tags: android, google-play, device

I would like to know, by what criteria google exclude a device, from an app that we have loaded on play store.
For example the last app that I published, is supported from only 2000 devices ca.
Then more than 2000 devices are excluded.
Why?
By what criteria google exclude a device?
What can I do to ensure that my app is available on more devices?
Thank in advance.
Helmut

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Answer (score 3):

Minimum screen size, minimum API level, requiring a touchscreen, a camera, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Google play filters the application based on the features given in the manifest like **Screen Size -supports-screen**, **Device Configuration - uses-configuration**, **Device Features- uses-feature** , **Software Library -uses-library**, **Permissions-uses-permission**, **SDK levels-uses-sdk**

Google Play uses other application characteristics to determine whether to show or hide an application for a particular user on a given device, as described in the table below.

**Publishing Status** -Only published applications will appear in searches and browsing within Google Play.
                   Even if an app is unpublished, it can be installed if users can see it in their Downloads area among their purchased, installed, or recently uninstalled apps.If an application has been suspended, users will not be able to reinstall or update it, even if it appears in their Downloads.

**Priced Status** - Not all users can see paid apps. To show paid apps, a device must have a SIM card and be running Android 1.1 or later, 
                and it must be in a country (as determined by SIM carrier) in which paid apps are available.

**Country Targeting** -When you upload your app to Google Play, you can select the countries in which to distribute your app under Pricing and Distribution.
                   The app will then be available to users in only the countries you select.

**CPU Architecture (ABI)** -An application that includes native libraries that target a specific CPU architecture (ARM EABI v7 or x86, for example) 
                        are visible only on devices that support that architecture.

**Copy-Protected Applications** -Google Play no longer supports the Copy Protection feature in the Developer Console and no longer filters apps based on it. 
                            To secure your app, please use Application Licensing instead. See Replacement for Copy Protection for more information.